# Java Model Exception when saving

Tags: java, xtext

everytime I test my grammar in a new eclipse window I get some exceptions on saving.
And dont know why.
I think maybe xtext is expecting an java project. Cause I tryed it with a java project and then it works without any exception.
I extended an example project (homeautomation). So maybe its there implemented. But I couldnt figure out where
Can you please tell me why xtext is expecting a java project.

Here my code:

```
    /*******************************************************************************
 * Copyright (c) 2015 itemis AG (http://www.itemis.eu) and others.
 * All rights reserved. This program and the accompanying materials
 * are made available under the terms of the Eclipse Public License v1.0
 * which accompanies this distribution, and is available at
 * http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html
 *******************************************************************************/
grammar org.eclipse.xtext.example.homeautomation.RuleEngine with org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xbase

import "http://www.eclipse.org/xtext/xbase/Xbase" as xbase
generate ruleEngine "http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/example/RuleEngine"

Model:
    (declarations += GIHeader) ;
    //declarations+=Declaration*;

GIHeader: //General Information about Test
    KWHeader
;

Declaration:
   Section;

KWHeader: 
    ('CLASSIFICATION' | 'classification') PROPERTY_VALUE+ (properties+=Property+) &
   ('NAME' | 'name')                     PROPERTY_VALUE+ (properties+=Property+) &
   ('PROJECTS' |'projects')              PROPERTY_VALUE+ (properties+=Property+) &
   ('NUMBER' | 'number')                 PROPERTY_VALUE+ (int+=PropNumber+)      &
   ('testcase' | 'test case' | 'TESTCASE' | 'TEST CASE' | 'Testcase' | 'Test Case')
   (properties+=Property)+
;

// We modify the concrete syntax of two Xbase expressions and make them indentation-aware
XBlockExpression returns xbase::XExpression: 
    {xbase::XBlockExpression}
    BEGIN
        (expressions+=XExpressionOrVarDeclaration ';'?)*
    END;

XSwitchExpression returns xbase::XExpression:
    {xbase::XSwitchExpression}
    'switch' (=>('(' declaredParam=JvmFormalParameter ':') switch=XExpression ')'
        | =>(declaredParam=JvmFormalParameter ':')? switch=XExpression)
    BEGIN
        (cases+=XCasePart)*
        ('default' ':' default=XExpression )?
    END;


Property:
 id=ID | int=INT | prop=PROPERTY_VALUE | spec=SPECIAL
 ;

PropNumber:
   int=INT | spec=SPECIAL
;

 // The following synthetic tokens are used for the indentation-aware blocks
terminal BEGIN: 'synthetic:BEGIN';  // increase indentation
terminal END: 'synthetic:END';      // decrease indentation


terminal WS: ('\t'|'\r'|'\n')+;

PROPERTY_VALUE: (':' | '=');// !('\n' | '\r')*;

SPECIAL: (' '|'/'|';'|','|'!'|'§'|'$'|'%'|'&'|'('|')'|'='|'?'|'*'|'+'|'.'|'-'|'>'|'<'|'|'|'['|']')
           (' '|'/'|';'|','|'!'|'§'|'$'|'%'|'&'|'('|')'|'='|'?'|'*'|'+'|'.'|'-'|'>'|'<'|'|'|'['|']')*
;
// Single line comment  
terminal SL_COMMENT: '#' !('\n'|'\r')* ('\r'? '\n')?;
```

And the exception.

```
1849463 [Worker-21] ERROR org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.XtextBuilder  - Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [asdf does not exist]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [asdf does not exist]
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.JDTAwareSourceFolderProvider.getSourceFolders(JDTAwareSourceFolderProvider.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.EclipseOutputConfigurationProvider.createAndOverlayOutputConfiguration(EclipseOutputConfigurationProvider.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.EclipseOutputConfigurationProvider.getOutputConfigurations(EclipseOutputConfigurationProvider.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.BuilderParticipant.getOutputConfigurations(BuilderParticipant.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.BuilderParticipant.build(BuilderParticipant.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.RegistryBuilderParticipant$DeferredBuilderParticipant.build(RegistryBuilderParticipant.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.RegistryBuilderParticipant.build(RegistryBuilderParticipant.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.XtextBuilder.doBuild(XtextBuilder.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.XtextBuilder.fullBuild(XtextBuilder.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.XtextBuilder.build(XtextBuilder.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [asdf does not exist]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.newNotPresentException(JavaElement.java:556)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getPerProjectInfoCheckExistence(JavaModelManager.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getPerProjectInfo(JavaProject.java:1909)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getRawClasspath(JavaProject.java:1931)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.JDTAwareSourceFolderProvider.getSourceFolders(JDTAwareSourceFolderProvider.java:34)
    ... 21 more

!ENTRY org.apache.log4j 4 0 2015-08-06 13:29:47.262
!MESSAGE org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.XtextBuilder  - Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [asdf does not exist]

!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [asdf does not exist]
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.JDTAwareSourceFolderProvider.getSourceFolders(JDTAwareSourceFolderProvider.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.EclipseOutputConfigurationProvider.createAndOverlayOutputConfiguration(EclipseOutputConfigurationProvider.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.EclipseOutputConfigurationProvider.getOutputConfigurations(EclipseOutputConfigurationProvider.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.BuilderParticipant.getOutputConfigurations(BuilderParticipant.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.BuilderParticipant.build(BuilderParticipant.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.RegistryBuilderParticipant$DeferredBuilderParticipant.build(RegistryBuilderParticipant.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.RegistryBuilderParticipant.build(RegistryBuilderParticipant.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.XtextBuilder.doBuild(XtextBuilder.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.XtextBuilder.fullBuild(XtextBuilder.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.XtextBuilder.build(XtextBuilder.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [asdf does not exist]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.newNotPresentException(JavaElement.java:556)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getPerProjectInfoCheckExistence(JavaModelManager.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getPerProjectInfo(JavaProject.java:1909)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getRawClasspath(JavaProject.java:1931)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.JDTAwareSourceFolderProvider.getSourceFolders(JDTAwareSourceFolderProvider.java:34)
    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Xbase which does not work in non-java projects. So yes, that's causing the issue for you. However, the exception could be more friendly. Could you please file a ticket?

Comment: Ok tried again and found out how to switch off xtend. Works. Sure I can. Is eclipse bugzilla wright?

Comment: Yes, Eclipse bugzilla is the bugtracker we use.

Comment: I also have this issue, why isn't the exception caught by Xtext ? The line fragment = xbase.XbaseGeneratorFragment {} has a lot of other potentially desirable effects outside the java world. It shouldn't crash on non java nature projects.